# В проекте Unity не работает звук (у миксера все бегунки на нулях)

Tags: unity3d, аудио

Выставлял тут:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Создавал GameObject-"Background Music":
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

с скриптом Sounds.cs:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

    public class Sounds : MonoBehaviour
    {
        private AudioSource audio;
        void Start()
        {
            audio = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
            audio.Play();
        }
    }
```

Но музыка не проигрывается. У меня всё через миксер сделано :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И у миксера все бегунки на нулях , когда запускается сцена и проигрывается :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Не пойму что не так делаю. Unity 2019.3.2f1 (64-bit) ... Звук в наушниках есть, когда включаю mp3

Answer (score 0):

У камеры добавьте Audio Listener:[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И не забудьте :
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]